# How to read, save and display images, encoded in csv format

Tags: csv, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, data-science

[image: Part of a csv file]

I've got some images for training and testing a tensorflow model encoded in csv format. Is there a way to extract those images and / or save them in jpg like format?

Part of the file can be seen above as a opened in excel as a screenshot. If you prefer text to hyperlinks, here is a part of it in a form of a text:

```
label   pixel1  pixel2 ...

6       149     149    ...
 
5       126     128    ...

10      85      88     ...

0       203     205    ...
```

There are 785 columns and 7173 rows in total. I have no idea how to deal with that.

Comment: If you are just planning to use them for training/validation, you do not need to extract images and/or save them as other formats. Do you know what type of model you want to apply ?
Also, what does label mean, is it the number of the row ? Can you be a little more explicit, please.

Comment: I'm working on a project for sign language detection. I needed more data, so I found it here: https://www.kaggle.com/datamunge/sign-language-mnist?select=amer_sign2.png                                                                                                  However, I still don't quite understand how it all works. I found similar videos like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U                                                  
but they don't work with csv. So I wonder if there is a way to somehow process these images. As for the label, I'm trying to figure that out too

Answer (score 0):

You can read any row, plot it and save it as image like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# read csv file
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
# read pixels 
images = np.array(df.iloc[:,1:])
labels = np.array(df.iloc[:,0])
# select random number between 0 and 7172
index = 2
# reshape 784 rows to 28 height x 28 width
sample_image = images[index,:].reshape(28,28)
# import plt for displaying image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# plot image
plt.imshow(sample_image)
plt.axis('off')
# plot it's label
print(labels[index])
# save image
plt.savefig("./image{}_label{}".format(index,labels[index]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
# first i create a dummy dataset to work on
data = make_classification(10000, n_features=784, random_state=1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0], columns=[str(f'col_{i}') for i in range(784)])
df['label'] = data[1]

# Now we create a img_vector and labels array from the dataframe
img_vector = df[[str(f'col_{i}') for i in range(784)]].values
labels = df['label'].values

# splitting the data

# Now we creating the dataset
def get_img(inputs, labels):
    # here you have 784 pixels which usually represent a 28*28 image with 1 channel
    # hence I reshape it that way
    img = tf.reshape(inputs, (28,28,1))
    # you can also add some augmentation
    img = tf.image.flip_left_right(img)
    img = tf.image.flip_up_down(img)
    return img, labels

# We pass the img_vector and labels to the make the dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_mat, train_label))
# Map the dataset to get images form it.
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(get_img).batch(16)

# same for valid dataset
valid_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((valid_mat, valid_label))
valid_dataset = valid_dataset.map(get_img).batch(16)

# A sanity check
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sample = None
for i in train_dataset:
    sample = i
    break
    
plt.imshow(sample[0][0])

# Creating a model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3,3, input_shape=(28,28,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

# Finally train the model
model.fit(train_dataset, 
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=valid_dataset)
```

Also, if you ever take a dataset from Kaggle you will usually find a sample notebook for that dataset in the code section.

Comment: This post does not provide an answer for the question. The question asks about read csv file (which is not available in your code). Also asks for saving images, which is not in your code. You added the code for creating a model and training which is not requested!!

Comment: @Kaveh Yes, I know but when I read the comments I saw that he want to use these to create a model and hence I walked the extra mile.